# Where can I find an historically accurate ordinary items database for dungeon-stocking and art

Tags: identification, technology, historical-research, anthropology, research

I swear I had found in the comments of one of Matthew Colville's "stocking the dungeon" videos a link to an enormous database of accurate lists of ordinary items that list REAL items that could be found in any room, no matter when in time, or where in the world.  This would be very useful for stocking a dungeon realistically, and also for good set design in theatre period pieces.

I think these accurate lists were made because they're useful for some anthropology or archaeological reasons, but I'm not sure.

I used to have a link bookmarked to that enormous database of accurate lists of ordinary items that list REAL items that could be found in any room, no matter when in time, or where in the world, such as the objects in a 1700's tepee in North America, or the ordinary stuff at an early Roman estate, or whatever would be in a 1920's gymnasium. Seriously, anywhere, anytime accurate lists, it was an amazing database.  And then my computer blew up.  I can't remember the site name, and I can't find a link to it, search engines aren't coughing it up no matter how cleverly I use a thesaurus.

This would be very useful for stocking a dungeon realistically, and also for good set design in theatre period pieces.

But for the life of me, I can't find it again!  All of the search term combinations I can think of don't bring it up.

- Estate Inventory of dead people, For legal end-of-life property transfer law
- rental-fire-flood-earthquake insurance
- survey of households

The data may have come from the insurance industry; lists of personal property itemized just in case a future claim would need to be made against an insurance policy, renter's insurance, and the like.

I don't want an ordinary random item generator, those are easy to find and they don't provide the depth of realism for setting-the-stage that I'm looking for.

I'm specifically looking for this particular database because it has REAL and COMPLETE lists of each & every single last mundane item that were actually in such places at those times, and this isn't the kind of detail a GM can generate from their own mind and definitely not from somebody's random table with even 100 things on it, which sounds like a lot but isn't.  I want to use it for set design in all kinds of art, not just RPGs.

The database had such minor details as how many sticks of gum were left in a pack, how many individual socks were present, how many forks, knives, and egg slicers were in this one drawer in a kitchen, how many screws were in the workshop cabinet, etc.

I asked in another forum, and somebody mentioned that it might have something to do with "Household Survey", and I suspect now that the database might have been a real-world tool for tracking wealth or poverty across time & space? I've searched some more based on that, but I still can't find it.

Maybe you have a link to something like this?

Comment: Can you remember whether this was published as a professional research database (i.e. one created by a museum or university) or sourced by an amateur as a personal project?

Comment: Have you searched the questions on [Role-Playing Games SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/)? You might find that others have been down the same path.

Comment: Role-Playing locked my question a year ago as supposedly being a request for a recommendation, which it wasn't.  It is lost-and-found question about something I lost and hope they had seen too.  Also, someone there said I should ask here, so please, please, please don't give me the run-around and tell me to go back there, please be more helpful and less harmfully judgemental than they were.

Comment: I know not whether it was a pro or amateur search tool, only that results from historic locations such as dig sites or inventoried factories & homes used real data.  Even a search for what could be found on real sea vessels or spacecraft returned real data.  But it would also come up with a realistic guess about what could be found on future space stations or starships if you searched for a future date.

Comment: If the complete database included items from the future then it's almost certainly a tool that was made either for the RPG community or for writers of sci-fi/fantasy fiction. So, it's unlikely to be widely known in the history mainstream. Presumably, you've searched all of the comments on Matthew Colville's "stocking the dungeon" videos to try to find it again?

Comment: Yes, I searched everything by hand, and used a search plugin too.  Perhaps the video I discovered on is now gone.  But surely the database website still exists.

Comment: Yes, I searched everything by hand, and used a search plugin too.  Perhaps the video I discovered on is now gone.  But surely the database website still exists.

Comment: I know about one DB of the kind that exists in any state - it is the DB of everything that is kept by Defence ministries in different states. For different uses. But I am afraid, they are a bit secret.